# Outer Joinning two table in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this two arrays:

```
  Array ( [291] => 3 [292] => 1 [293] => 3 )

  Array ( [291] => 3 [292] => 1 )
```

I need a php function to join out the two and have a result look like:

```
Array ( [293] => 3 )
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to compute the array_difference, you should use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
<?php
$a1=array ( "291" => 3, "292" => 1, "293" => 3 );
$a2=array ( "291" => 3, "292" => 1 ) ;

$result=array_diff_assoc($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
?>
```